# understanding casting in this program

Tags: java, logic

```
byte b = 5;
byte c = ~5;
```

this code if written in java gives error that cannot convert from int to byte.
Also if i do

```
int c = ~5;
```

it gives -6 as result however i was expecting 3. What is the reason and how can i do a not to achieve 3 as result.

Comment: Why are you expecting ~5 to give 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a negative number and not a positive because the byte primitive (as is short, int, long, etc.) is signed - so the most significant bit is flipped so it represents a negative number (using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).) Invert all the bits on a positive number and it'll become negative (and vice versa.)

That said, you wouldn't get 3 anyway if it didn't - 5 is 101 in binary, which would produce 010 (2, not 3.)

As to why it has to be put in an int, from memory that's because the JLS states that all integer arithmetic has a return type of "at least" an int. It's the same reason as if you do `byte b = 1+1` it still won't work, even though the result clearly fits into a byte.

Comment: The addition example isn't good, because this particular example **will** compile correctly (since `1+1` is a constant expression). `byte b = 1; b = 1+b;` will **not** compile.

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand the error.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 => 5
Applying the "~" operator:
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 => -6 in the complement 2.
```

What you cold do is, but not very good, just to understanding the problem:
    byte c = (byte) (0xFF) & ~5;

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 => -6 
Applying & 0xFF
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111                                           
Results:
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111010 => 250 
So you cast to byte:
-------- -------- -------- 11111010 => -6
```

A simple:
    byte c = (byte) ~5;
could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
byte b = 5;
```

is short hand for

```
byte b = (byte) 5;
```

it does the casting for you as its a constant expression the compiler can evaluate at compile time.

Also

```
byte b = ~5;
```

and even

```
final int i = 5;
byte b = ~i;
```

compile fine.  Note: if `i` is not final, the second line does not compile.

---

Calculating a negative is the same as taking the complement and adding 1.

neg(a) = comp(a) + 1 or -a = ~a + 1 or ~a = -a - 1

so you would expect ~5 to be -5 - 1 = -6.

Comment: `~5` is a constant expression, just as `5` is.

Comment: I have changed it to a "non-literal".  What would you call it?

Comment: I would call it a constant expression. It also **doesn't** require casting for that exact same reason.

Answer (score 0):

the bit representation of 5 is 00000101
then ~5 is 11111010

it's 2's complement is 00000110 which is bit representation of 6 and 11111010 is bit representation of -6.